# App architecture: directives vs. controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have a big app, which contains many layouts and subviews.
Looks like (simplified):
http://plnkr.co/edit/x4kleCCQH5Hsy6dcjgXe?p=preview

So, I have many directives and services. And only 2-4 simple controllers (10 - 20 lines of code). All logic stored into big directives, which contain many small directives. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I'm approaching it is.

- Directives contain view logic, not business logic. This is also where DOM-messing about happens if needed.
- Controllers are fairly thin, have minimal business logic.
- Angular Services are where most of the heavy lifting is done.

If you have logic that needs to be re-used by multiple areas/controllers or is stateful - it's probably a better fit to put into a Service than a Directive.

Depending on your app/architecture - you could be posting to a server, and having the heavy BL happen on the server side.

The Angular docs have a nice bit on [Using Directives Correctly](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) that has a few pointers.

Comment: Is it just me, or does it seem ironic that your "Using Directives Correctly" link points to a page describing Controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good to me.

At some point in the [DoubleClick talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJoAnVRIVQo), the speaker says something similar to "make controllers as thin as possible."

Answer (score 0):

The link was busted... a working link to the same guide is here:
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller